# Crystal report not run when two version installed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports

I have created Crystal report using version 13.0.17.2096.
So i installed 64 bit setup on client machine.it runs successfully but client also Required crystal report version  13.0.0.99  for old project when i install second one first one stops working. client require both version but any one project not working when i install two CR  how to fix this problem..??

**Using CR-13.0.17.2096 in  WPF Application in Visual Studio 2015**

**and Using CR- 13.0.0.99 in  C# in Visual Studio 2010**